# Good Compact Framework reference implementations

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Are there any good .net Compact Framework reference implementations (w/ source) out there that demonstrate good practices for developing on WM-enabled devices?

My main area of concern and uncertainty is with Data Access. ORMs seem out of the question (do they even exist? are they feasible on resource-constrained environments?) and the method suggested by Microsoft (DataSets) just makes me cringe.

Any tips/links/pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ORMs, Linq-To-SQL works on WinMob 6.0 and 6.5 if you are using the 3.5 version of the Compact Framework and SQL Server Compact Edition.

This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321573587) is excellent and very timely.  It was just released about a week ago.  The authors do a great job with a very low signal-to-noise ratio and they focus on Windows Mobile-specific best practices which is what you were asking for.

[Compact Framework 3.5 book http://img.flipkart.com/bk_imgs/582/9780321573582.jpg](http://img.flipkart.com/bk_imgs/582/9780321573582.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft put out a number of reference/sample implementations with source code and documentation etc. One example would be

[Windows Mobile Line of Business Accelerator 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=428E4C3D-64AD-4A3D-85D2-E711ABC87F04&displaylang=en)

I'm not exactly sure of "best" practice (is there any such thing?). However these reference implementations are usually very good at showing one way in which an end to end solution can be put together and point out some of the most common stumbling blocks etc.